# How do I re-acquire a token from AAD using vue-msal after I close the browser tab and open the page again?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have the following code for a Vue JS based single page application connecting to Azure AD via vue-msal which works when I:

- open up the web app for the very first time

  - takes me to the AAD login page
  - once logged in, redirects me back to my app
- I can then do a `console.log()` and print out my access token etc to verify login was successful and token was acquired successfully

Now suppose I close the browser tab. My login session is still there (after all, I haven't deleted any cookies!) but now my access token is gone (presumably because it was saved as a variable rather than in a cookie). How do I re-acquire the access token when I open up a new tab and navigate to my application?

```
# main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import msal from 'vue-msal';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(msal, {
  auth: {
    clientId: "CLIENT_ID_OF_MY_SINGLE_PAGE_APPLICATION"
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/",
    requireAuthOnInitialize: true
  },
  request: {
    scopes: [ `user.read`, `https://backend-api-hosted-on-functionapp.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation` ]
  },
  graph: {
    callAfterInit: true,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage"
  }
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  data: function() {
    return {
      dummyVariable: 'dummyValue',
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("User auth status is: " + this.$msal.isAuthenticated());
    console.log("User data object: " + JSON.stringify(this.$msal)) // shows the bearer token the first time, but when I then close the tab and re-open the tab, I see nothing here
  }

}}).$mount('#app')
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Am I "meant to be" re-acquiring a new token if the application is loaded up again? Is this conventional practice?
2. If so, how do I go about doing it? I tried using using:

```
    if ((this.$msal.data.isAuthenticated == false) || (this.$msal.data.accessToken == false)) {
      console.log("New token required");
      this.$msal.signIn();
      console.log("User data object: " + JSON.stringify(this.$msal))
    }
```

But that doesn't give me anything back unfortunately.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Azure Authentication flow unfortunately. However you could just store the token in a cookie yourself. Store it along with an expiration time and eiher use the stored token for auth or send the user back to sign in if it expired.
However, most cloud services don't require you to manage this manually, so there should be an easier way to achieve this using Azure.

Comment: I was thinking this also but a part of me feels this is "bad practice" as one would hope libraries like MSAL developed by Microsoft would manage a lot of this "grunt work" automatically and if I can't get it working, then that must be indicative of developer-error on my part!

Comment: Try setting the `cacheLocation` option to `localStorage`, as `sessionStorage` gets cleared when you close the Browser Tab. For reference, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-between-browser-tabs

Comment: Well now I feel silly. Turns out this isn't a bug with my code per-se, but rather a bug with vue-msal itself according to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/mvertopoulos/vue-msal/issues/33 - in the meantime, I might downgrade my vue-msal version (or maybe just use native MSAL instead of using vue-msal)

Comment: Hi chivano! Would you consider posting this as an answer instead of a comment? It makes it easier for people having similar issues to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the off chance anyone else ends up looking at this question, this isn't an issue with my code as such, but an ongoing issue between vue-msal and the msal packages, as explained in this GH issue: https://github.com/mvertopoulos/vue-msal/issues/33